# transfer drawn content from one jcomponent to onther

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a Java program with two textareas and a button. I want to allow the user to write one one textarea using a touch pen or mouse and when he/she clicks the button, the drawn content should be send to textarea no 2.

So the textarea where the user is writing on, I gave a mousemotion listener with paintComponent method in it.
When I run the application, I have realized that texarea method `getText()` and `setText()` can't set or get the drawn content.

Is there way I can achieve the above task? I have also tried `JPanel` but it doesn't have the `setContent()` method.

I appreciate any help.

This is my **first textarea** where user is writing on with touchpen.

```
public class Area1 extends JTextArea {

    int pointcount = 0;
    Point[] points = new Point[10000];

    public Area1() {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                if (pointcount < points.length) {
                    points[pointcount] = event.getPoint();
                    ++pointcount;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < pointcount; i++) {
            g.fillOval(points[i].x, points[i].y, 4, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my overall application with **textarea2** and **button**

```
public class Handwriting extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea area2;
    private JButton b1;
    Area1 area1;

    public Handwriting() {
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        area1 = new Area1();
        area1.setRows(30);
        area1.setColumns(30);
        area2 = new JTextArea(30, 30);
        b1 = new JButton("Copy");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (event.getSource() == b1) {
                    area2.setText(area1.getText());
                }
            }
        });
        box.add(area1);
        box.add(b1);
        box.add(area2);
        add(box);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handwriting hand = new Handwriting();
        hand.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hand.setSize(500, 500);
        hand.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to make one class as a **Inner Class** of the other , that way even private instance fields can be accessed

Comment: i dont see how making one class an inner class of the other would help me be able to copy paste drawn content from textarea1 to textarea2. please give me more explanation

Comment: Or try using a j panel , retrieve the drawn content from it by passing the panel itself to method say create , and create a buffered image from the panel ,cast it to a imageicon,set it to a label , add the label to the second panel , try searching around and let me know if this method work ,

Comment: i tried but am getting nothing into area2 which i have renamed it as jpanel together with area1. do you know any example that worked?